# Angular i18n configuration on ng serve

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am following the guidance on internationalization on https://angular.io/guide/i18n

When configuring my angular.json I configured the serve section as below:

```
   "serve": { 
        "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:production"
            },
            "zh": {
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:zh"
            }
     }
```

But when I try to use "ng serve --configurations=zh", keep hitting this

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'zh' is not set in the workspace.
```

I already setup all the necessary locale files required. Anyone can help?

Comment: You need to add the "zh" configuration to the `build` target as well. Show us the full angular.json file.

Comment: @David That did the trick! I didn't add in the build section thought that was not required. Many thanks!